# Get the quantity from the description in Pyspark using regex

Tags: regex, pyspark

I have a dataframe that captures code and its description, we need to extract quantity from the description. How can I extract quantity using regex, it is like number followed by G/KG/L/ML

df

```
code description
1    ABC CHILLIE POWDER 100G
2    DEF POWDER 200G
3    DIL PDWR POWDER 100G
4    RAIN HILL HERB SOU GREED 40G 2 1FRE
5    DEAR CHILLI 200G+COCO POWDER 330ML
6    DIL PDWR 10L POWDER
```

result_df

```
code description                                 qty
1    ABC CHILLIE POWDER 100G                     100G
2    DEF POWDER 200G                             200G
3    DIL PDWR POWDER 100G                        100G
4    RAIN HILL HERB SOU GREED 40G 2 1FRE         40G
5    DEAR CHILLI 200G+COCO POWDER 330ML          200G
6    DIL PDWR 10L POWDER                         10L
```

I am using

```
df.withColumn("qty", F.regex_extract(F.col("description"), "\dG", 1)
```

Comment: Try `df['qty']=df['description'].str.extract(r'\b(\d+[A-Z])\b')`, or with `r'\b(\d+[GL])\b'` regex

Comment: not working in pyspark

Comment: Sorry, just try `r'\b(\d+[GL])\b'` in your code

Comment: thanks, how can we include number followed by G, KG, L, ML ? this skips for 500ML, r'\b(\d+(G|L|ML))\b'?

Comment: I posted an answer below, please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
df.withColumn("qty", F.regex_extract(F.col("description"), r"(\d+\s?(?:K?G|M?L))\b", 1)
```

The `(\d+\s?(?:K?G|M?L))\b` pattern matches

- `(\d+\s?(?:K?G|M?L))` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits,
  - `\s?` - 1 or 0 whitespaces, then
  - `(?:K?G|M?L)` - either an optional `K` and a `G` or an optional `M` and then `L`
- `\b` - word boundary.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9miqfT/1/).

Comment: Thank you wiktor, it skips descr like below where there is space after number, can we suggest that as weell pls?
   1               SUM CREAM OF TOMATO SOUP 100 G, 

    2               REGULAR FOAM100ML